# How can i add a Start button to this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, audio

I'm trying to figure out how I can add a start button to play a javascript game by replacing the audio in the background. I came across this game, the way it works is as soon as you load the page the music plays in the background and the games already started. When I removed the audio link, the game paused after the players 3 lives are up, if I leave the audio in, then when the 3 lives are up you can see your points and a pop up message, can someone please help me understand this

here is a link to the game so you can look at the code and understand what I'm trying to say : https://jsfiddle.net/74nbrdak/embedded/result/

```
<div>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="500"></canvas>
</div>

<audio id="background-music" preload="auto" autoplay loop>
<source 
src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5r3iu7kjsl0mx81/Wildfire%20Cut%20Loopable.wav"       type="audio/wav">
```

```
 function ShowGamesFinished() {
var message = gamesfinished[Math.floor(Math.random() *     gamesfinished.length)];

 document.getElementById("background-music").pause();
```

Comment: This looks like incomplete code. Provide more code so that we can understand what's going on.

Comment: @AdityaDan.i've added a link where you can see the code

Answer (score 1):

> When I removed the audio link, the game paused after the players 3 lives are up, if I leave the audio in, then when the 3 lives are up you can see your points and a pop up message, can someone please help me understand this

So, In the second scenario when the audio element is on the page, the game works just as the creator intended.
In the first scenario when the audio element isn't on the page, the game works fine until the function that handles the game over is called. What causes the problem in that function is this line `document.getElementById("background-music").pause();`. Since the audio element doesn't exist, it throws an error and the game over screen isn't drawn. Hope that this helps

Comment: This is the key! Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much! that was my main problem I couldn't identify, now the only thing I need help with is having a start / pause button so the game doesn't start as soon as the page loads, could you help please?

Comment: `var gameLoop = setInterval(Update, updateTime);` This is the piece of code that starts the game. Write a simple function that assigns the `setInterval` value to `gameLoop`. But, for this to work with all of the code, declare the gameLoop variable in the global scope and then assign it the value like I mentioned. Then just run that function on the `click` event of the button.

Comment: Could you know me another screenshot please? don't you also have to create a pause button?

Comment: If you want to pause the game, clear the interval `gameLoop`

Comment: can you show me what the complete code would look like please?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pure javascript Without any external libraries, you can initialize your canvas and on a click of the button you can start animating the canvas and your game starts.
let me know If you don't get my answer.

Comment: if you wouldn't mind could you please show me what this would look like?

Comment: `function animate(){`

`    c.clearRect(0,0,window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);`
`    requestAnimationFrame(animate);`
`    for(var i = 0; i < circleArray.length ; i++){`
`        var circle = circleArray[i];`
        `circle.update();`
    `}`

`}`

`//init your canvas`
`init()`
`document.getElementById('start').onclick = function(){`
`    //this function will start the animation in canvas`
   ` animate();`
`};`

Comment: could you lay this out in the proper format please? it looks very confusing to me

Comment: here is the link to the screenshot.     https://photos.app.goo.gl/kmNh6fmHPjTPedQ22

Comment: does this solution get rid of the audio problem? I'm trying to remove audio with it affecting the game

Comment: `document.getElementById("background-music").pause();` remove this line and the game will work fine.

Comment: thank you so much! if you wouldn't mind. how could I add a start pause button so the game doesn't automatically start when the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, removing the audio tag should not have any effect at all on the javascript. The audio plays upon openeing the page because the audio tag has the autoplay attribute.

All of the javascript code seems to be just within a script tag, so it will also autorun once the page gets opened. What you could try is wrapping the entire code from the fiddle into a function and just bind it to your button.

Something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <style>
    h1 {
      font-family: Architects Daughter;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 48pt;
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    h2 {
      font-family: Architects Daughter;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 28pt;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    span {
      display: block;
      font-family: Arial;
      text-align: center;
      margin-bottom: 2px;
    }

    div {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    canvas {
      border: 2px solid #CC3333;
    }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <div>
      <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="360"></canvas>
    </div>
    <button id="start_game">Start</button>
    <script>
var run_game = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var WIDTH = canvas.width;
var HEIGHT = canvas.height;
var updateTime = 20; // Milliseconds
var keys = [false, false, false];

var score = 0;
var kills = 0;

// Player Size = 50x18
var playerHealth = 3;
var playerX = WIDTH / 2;
var playerY = HEIGHT - 20;
var playerSpeed = 6;

var lazerSpeed = 16;
var lazerReloadDistance = playerY - 120;
var lazerLoaded = true;
var lazers = [];

var letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
var maxEnemies = 12;
var enemySpeed = 4;
var enemies = [];

function Clear() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#404040";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
}

function DrawHealth(health) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#E52B50";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#E52B50";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.font = "18px Arial";
  ctx.textAlign = "start";

  var hearts = "";

  if (health == 3) {
    hearts = "<3 <3 <3";
  }
  else if (health == 2) {
    hearts = "<3 <3 X";
  }
  else if (health == 1) {
    hearts = "<3 X X";
  }
  else {
    hearts = "X X X";
  }

  ctx.fillText(hearts, 10, 25);
}

function DrawScore() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#FFFF00";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.font = "18px Arial";
  ctx.textAlign = "end";
  ctx.fillText(score, WIDTH - 10, 25);
}

function DrawPlayer(x, y) {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#1E90FF";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#1E90FF";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.font = "24px Arial";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.fillText("</^\\>", x, y);
}

function Lazer() {
    this.x = playerX;
  this.y = playerY - 38;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.shadowColor = "#FFFF00";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    this.y -= lazerSpeed;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 2, 18);
  }
}

function DrawLazers() {
    // Check if the last lazer fired is far enough away to fire another
    if (lazers.length != 0) {
    if (lazers[lazers.length - 1].y <= lazerReloadDistance) {
        lazerLoaded = true;
    }
    }
  else {
    lazerLoaded = true;
  }

    for (var i = 0; i < lazers.length; i++) {
    var currentLazer = lazers[i];

    // Still on screen
    if (currentLazer.y > -20) {
        currentLazer.draw();
    }
    else {
        lazers.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}

function Enemy(x) {
    this.x = x;
  this.y = 0;
  this.health = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4);
  this.speed = enemySpeed / this.health;

  var letterIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length);
  this.letter = letters.substr(letterIndex, 1);

  this.size = 24 + (this.health * 4); // Font size based on health
  ctx.font = this.size+"px Arial";

  this.width = ctx.measureText(this.letter).width;
  this.height = this.size * 0.75; // Approximate height;

  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0040";
    ctx.shadowColor = "#FF0040";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
    ctx.font = this.size+"px Arial";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    this.y += this.speed;

    ctx.fillText(this.letter, this.x, this.y);
  }
}

function DrawEnemies() {
    // Spawn new enemies
    if (Math.random() <= 0.05 && enemies.length < maxEnemies) {
    var randX = 40 + Math.floor(Math.random() * (WIDTH - 80));
    enemies.push(new Enemy(randX));
  }

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    var currentEnemy = enemies[i];

    if (currentEnemy.health <= 0) {
        enemies.splice(i, 1);
      score += 25;
      kills++;
      continue;
    }

    // Put enemies that passed the player back at the top
    if (currentEnemy.y > HEIGHT + currentEnemy.height) {
      currentEnemy.y = 0;
      continue;
    }

    currentEnemy.draw();
  }
}

var gameOverMessages = [
    "You're in a better place",
  "You're Cooked!",
  "You gave it your all",
  "At least you tried",
  "You're Ruined!",
  "You're Finished!"
];
function DrawGameOver() {
    var message = gameOverMessages[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameOverMessages.length)];
// after deleting the audio element, this doesnt work anymore.
// document.getElementById("background-music").pause();

    ctx.fillStyle = "#505050";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#505050";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.fillRect(50, (HEIGHT / 2) - 100, WIDTH - 100, 200)

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.shadowBlur = 15;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  ctx.font = "36pt Arial";
  ctx.fillText(message, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 - 40);

  ctx.textAlign = "end";
  ctx.font = "18pt Arial";
  ctx.fillText("Final Score - ", WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 30);

  ctx.textAlign = "start";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFF00";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#FFFF00";
  ctx.fillText(score, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 30);

  ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#FFFFFF";
  ctx.textAlign = "end";
  ctx.font = "18pt Arial";
  ctx.fillText("Total Kills - ", WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 60);

  ctx.textAlign = "start";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0040";
  ctx.shadowColor = "#FF0040";
  ctx.fillText(kills, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2 + 60);
}

////////////////////
// Core Functions //
////////////////////
var collidedEnemyIndex = -1;
function CheckCollision() {
    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {
    var currentEnemy = enemies[i];

    // Check if enemy hits player. The 2 is to account for the text width of the player
    if (
            currentEnemy.x <= playerX - 2 + 25 + (currentEnemy.width / 2) && 
        currentEnemy.x >= playerX - 2 - 25 - (currentEnemy.width / 2) && 
        currentEnemy.y >= playerY - 18 && 
        currentEnemy.y <= playerY + currentEnemy.height && 
        collidedEnemyIndex != enemies.indexOf(currentEnemy)
         )
    {
      collidedEnemyIndex = enemies.indexOf(currentEnemy);
      playerHealth--;
    }

    // Reset the index of the enemy colliding with the player
    if (collidedEnemyIndex == enemies.indexOf(currentEnemy) && currentEnemy.y < HEIGHT / 2) {
        collidedEnemyIndex = -1;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < lazers.length; j++) {
        var currentLazer = lazers[j];

      if (
         currentLazer.x <= currentEnemy.x + (currentEnemy.width / 2) && 
         currentLazer.x >= currentEnemy.x - (currentEnemy.width / 2) && 
         currentLazer.y <= currentEnemy.y
         )
      {
        currentEnemy.health--;
        score += 10;
        lazers.splice(lazers.indexOf(currentLazer), 1);
      }
    }
  }
}

function HandleInput() {
    if (keys[0] == true && keys[1] == false && playerX <= WIDTH - 30) {
    playerX += playerSpeed;
  }

  if (keys[1] == true && keys[0] == false && playerX >= 30) {
    playerX -= playerSpeed;
  }

  if (keys[2]) {
    if (lazerLoaded) {
      lazers.push(new Lazer());
      lazerLoaded = false;
    }
  }
}

function KeysDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

  // Right
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    keys[0] = true;
  }
  // Left
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    keys[1] = true;
  }

  // Up/Fire
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    keys[2] = true;
  }
}

function KeysUp(e) {
  // Right
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
    keys[0] = false;
  }
  // Left
  else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
    keys[1] = false;
  }

  // Up/Fire
  if (e.keyCode == 38) {
    keys[2] = false;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", KeysDown, true);
document.addEventListener("keyup", KeysUp, true);

function Update() {
    Clear();

  HandleInput();

  CheckCollision();

  DrawEnemies();

  DrawLazers();
  DrawPlayer(playerX, playerY);

  DrawHealth(playerHealth);
  DrawScore();

  if (playerHealth <= 0) {
    clearInterval(gameLoop);
    DrawGameOver();
  }
}

var gameLoop = setInterval(Update, updateTime);
};

document.querySelector( '#start_game' ).addEventListener( 'click', run_game );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please apply this to the code in the fiddle and see if it works by removing the entire audio? I would really appreciate it if you could show me a screenshot

Comment: Updated with the full code. It works now after I fixed Aditya's find.

Comment: you are a live saver! thank you so much! just one more thing, before I click start , you cannot see the game as it is white. is there a way to show the game but not play it until the user clicks the start button?

Comment: You can, but that would require quite the restructuring of the code, which is something I can't fix in 10 minutes. The 'good' solution would be to split all the rendering code into parts that can be rendered before, like the background, and parts that have to be run at game time, like the enemies.But since the DrawPlayers() function already needs thet players, you can't easily run it seperately. The 'bad' solution would be to just draw on the canvas yourself before the game starts.

Comment: I understand what you mean, so instead, how could I place an image screenshot of the game over the actual game then? the way I would want it to work is, when the user clicks start the image disappears and they can play the game that's underneath. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Thats what I mean with 'draw on the canvas'. Go to mozilla developer network (MDN) and look up the things a canvas can do. It's propably only one or two lines of code to change the background to some image.